# Connecting a simple array to a nested array logic confusion

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, logic

Let's say my first table controller is populated by a simple array.

```
var number = ["one", "two", "three"].
```

Then my second table controller is populated with a nested array.

```
var letter = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "I"]]
```

If the user selects "one" in the first table controller, the user would be able to see the letter array items "a, b, c" In the second table controller. The same goes with "two" and "d,e,f," and so on.
Im aware that index path refers to a section and row... But here is where my logic is strained.

Let me attempt to explain my confusion. So theoretically, I choose "three" in the number array. To my understanding, that would give me an index path of [0][2]... a section 0, row 2. With that in mind, the only real value I have to work with here is 2, which is a row value. Therefore, how am I supposed to connect this purely row value with a nested array/section from the letter array?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with swift, but the logic would be as follows. Take the index path of the table cell clicked in the first controller, pass it to the second one - then do a check via objectAtIndex: (past index path)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most programming languages, the first item in a swift array is 0

```
let array = [1,2,3]
array[0] // array[0] = 1
```

So when you get the row value of 2 and get

```
number[indexpath.row] //this will return "three"
```

You will be able to use the same with your letter array

```
letter[indexpath.row] //will return ["g", "h", "I"] when row = 2
```

You should also be able to see when you tapped the third row in your `UITableView` it will return 2 for the `indexpath.row`

Answer (score 0):

Swift comes with collection type of Dictionary.Dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value associations.
Unlike Arrays you can set index values of for each value.

```
var arr1=["a","b","c"]
var arr2=["d","e","f"]
var arr3=["g","h","i"]
var dict = ["one":arr1,"two":arr2,"three":arr3]
print(dict["one"]) // access the dictionary through its key value
```

Output will be ["a", "b", "c"]

You can refer this link if you want to read more about Dictionary in Swift.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

in your case you can initialize two arrays

```
var keys=["one","two","three"];
var arr1=["a","b","c"]
var arr2=["d","e","f"]
var arr3=["g","h","i"]
var dict = ["one":arr1,"two":arr2,"three":arr3]
```

You can populate your 1st table view with key array.
After that you can get selected value from did select method to get array value to populate  your 2nd table view

```
var selectedStr = "one"
var newArr = dict[selectedStr]//use this array to populate 2nd Table View.
```

Hope it helps.
Happy Coding.. !!